# Download a file in HTML

Tags: html

Hi I want to have the option on my site for the user to download a CSV file. I have used the code below

```
    <input type="button" value="Download as CSV file" onclick="window.location.href='call_log.csv'  " />
```

This does work but when the button is clicked the file is opened in another tab on my browser, What I want to happen is a download straight to the users default download folder

Can anyone help me please ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to modify the headers that the server sends out with your CSV file. You need to add this header:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="call_log.csv"
```

Comment: It won't work. You need to write the content of the file to the Response stream. Otherwise it will not work.

Comment: That is, from a programmatical point of view, correct. But since the poster didn't mention any programming language, I only included the part that actually makes the difference between inline display and offering a file for download.

Comment: True! Sorry I was assuming he is doing it in c#

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing the same for my portfolio and I found a very simple way to download my cv as pdf from my website's local files.
I made a link `<a>` as a button.

```
<a class="resume-btn" href="./resumes/UX Resume.pdf"> UX </a>
```

I tried it on Firefox, Opera, and Chrome, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you just make a ordinary link to the file, the browser should not leave the page it is on, but just download the file straight away:

```
<a href="call_log.csv">Link</a>
```

I know it works for a .zip file, but haven't tried with .csv

But if you are having problems you can try zip the csv :)